# Proving that $f$ is constant on $E$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$ and $a \in E \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$, where $E$ is compact and connected. Suppose also that for each $x \in E$ there is a $\delta_x >0$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $y \in B_{\delta_x}(x)$. Prove that $f$ is constant on $E$.

The definition that my book provides for being compact is as follows:The set $E$ is said to be compact if and only if every open covering of $E$ has a finite subcovering; that is, if and only if given any open covering $\{V_α\}_{α∈A}$ of $E$, there is a finite subset $A_0 = \{α_1, . . . , α_N\}$ of $A$ such that $E \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^N V_{a_j}$.

Similarly the definition of open covering is given as:

An open covering of $E$ is a collection of sets $\{V_α\}_{α∈A}$ such that each $V_α$ is
open and $E \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in A}V_{\alpha}$.

Is there any way that we can just pick our $B_{\delta_x}$ such that it is an open covering of $E$ since we know that $E$ is compact already so that $E \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{x\in E} B_{\delta_x}(x)$.

If not I am really just confused on how to start this question, if someone could just nudge me in the right direction I think I can get this problem down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the fact that $E$ is compact doesn't matter here.

Take $a\in E$, let $p=f(a)$ and define $F=\{x\in E\mid f(x)=p\}=f^{-1}\bigl(\{p\}\bigr)\cap E$. Then:

- $a\in F$ and therefore $F\ne\emptyset$;
- if $x\in E\setminus F$, then there is a $\delta_x>0$ such that $\bigl(\forall y\in B_{\delta_x}(x)\bigr):f(y)=f(x)$ and therefore $B_{\delta_x}(x)\subset E\setminus F$; so $E\setminus F$ is an open subset of $E$, which means that $F$ is a closed subset of $E$;
- if $x\in F$, then there is a $\delta_x>0$ such that $\bigl(\forall y\in B_{\delta_x}(x)\bigr):f(y)=p$ and therefore $B_{\delta_x}(x)\subset F$; so $F$ is open.

Since $F$ is non-empty, open, and closed, the fact that it is connected implies that $F=E$. In other words, $(\forall x\in E):f(x)=p$.